# Stepper motor with double output shaft

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor

I'm trying to modify a small DC stepper motor from a single output to double output. Could a stepper with one output (front) be fairly easily modified to double output (front and back)? For instance, stepper motors like below seems to have a bit of the output shaft protruded from the back.

[image]

Could the shaft somehow be shifted to the back to make double output? Will the torque and other ratings be affected as a result?

Comment: You may get lucky with a press tool or even a vise and a suitable jig, as the parts are usually press fit on cheap motors. Or you may write off a motor or two. If they are $1 or less each I'd buy a few and try it.

Comment: Do you mean the shaft is usually press fit on after the motor is fully assembled?

Comment: No, the rotor is press fit onto the shaft, then the stator etc are assembled round it and closed by folding metal tabs. But if you're lucky you can move the shaft, with the rotor supported against that fat bronze bearing, without dismantling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motors are carefully engineered devices.  Modifying one is costly, error prone, and most likely violates the specs.

Get a motor that has the shaft protruding at both ends.  That's a somewhat unusual requirement, so may be difficult to find.  Look around on various distributor web sites to see who makes roughly the kinds of small motors you are looking for, then look on the manufacturer web sites to see if any of them make what you want.

You should also step back and see if you can fix this problem at a higher level without requiring a weird part at the low level.  Even if you find the right motor, you'll be stuck later when that one part goes obsolete.  Designing with mainstream parts has the advantage of being able to find replacements without too much re-engineering when some of the components become unavailable later.

Answer (score 1):

Stepper motors, or rather motors in general, may be manufactured to have a shaft that extends out both ends of the unit. The greater majority of units sold though will have the shaft extending out one end only. The reason of this is simple - applicability to the needs of the end application.

Ability to modify an existing motor to push the shaft out from one end to cause it to extend out both ends may be possible in some instances but it depends entirely on the construction and design of a particular motor. So there is not a specific answer to your question other than to purchase a unit you are interested in and try taking it apart and seeing what may be possible. In lieu of that you need to put on your shopping hat and start looking at manufacturer web sites and find a motor that has dual extended shaft ends that would meet your needs.